# Scrolling tableview resets horizontal scroll view page control

Tags: swift

I have some odd behaviour in my app. I have a table view controller with static cells. In one of the cells I have a horizontal scroll view. The scroll view is connected to a page controller. The scroll view and page controller work fine however if I scroll the table view the scroll views page controller resets to the first page.

However, the actual scroll view contents do not so then if I scroll the scroll view again the page controller will jump back to the previous position.

I am using:

```
override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView){
  let pageWidth:CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame)
  let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1
   self.pageController.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}
```

to control the visuals of the page controller.

It seems like the above is also picking up the table view scroll did end. Any suggestions on how to stop the table view triggering the function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is check whether the `scrollview` is your table view:

```
override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView){

   // Add this 
   if scrollView == self.tableView
   {
        return;
   }

   let pageWidth:CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame)
   let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1
   self.pageController.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}
```

Comment: @puks1978 np glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old thread but you dont really need that tableview reference.

```
if scrollView is UITableView{
    return
}
//Do some stuff
```